# What terms should I use to refer to @angular/angular 2.0.0 when talking with friends?

Tags: angularjs

There are a lot of terms being used right now for the latest release from the Angular team. What term should I use?

Answer (score -1):

In general you can keep things simple and call it `Angular`. This is the term that will be used to refer to versions 2.0, 2.1, 3.0 and beyond (the team uses Semantic Versioning now, so version numbers will increase without the corresponding complete overhaul).

If you need to refer to an older version of angular, then feel free to specify the version number, such as `Angular 1.5` or even `AngularJS 1.5`.

Comment: Did you just answered your own question acting like a different person?

Comment: Question is off topic here...and should not be answered as a result. Please review site guidelines before creating self answered questions that are off topic